# Python Logger Logs Twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I've been reading up on logging, and I think I understand what is happening but I do not know how to correct it. I have a file where I want to set up my logger, and then I want my application to use that configured logger, here is my `logger.py` file:

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '{levelname} {asctime} {name} {lineno}: {message}', style='{')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Now, I have another file that handles certain functionality and it needs to use this logger. Let's call it `some_class.py` So what I have done is:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger.someClass')


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_something(self):
        logger.critical('A critical message')
```

Now in a `runner.py` file I do:

```
import logger

from some_class import SomeClass

SomeClass().do_something()
```

My output is:

```
CRITICAL 2019-10-04 07:38:38,579 mylogger 25: critical message
CRITICAL 2019-10-04 07:38:38,592 mylogger.SomeClass 12: A critical message
```

Now the problem is that I only want to show the class-level logger's message. I have also tried moving the logger inside the class as a class variable and then referring to `self.logger` instead but it yields the same result. Is there a way to disable the root logger or how would I only get one log message in this case?

Comment: I flagged this as duplicate. Anyway, the answer there says you need ```logger.propagate = False```.

Comment: That's what I needed, thank you

Comment: I'm glad to help. Please, take some time to upvote the right answer and encourage the author to keep up with the good work.