# Why is my logger logging twice shown on terminal screen?

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger but in one python file, it always print out logging info twice. For example,

```
class Runner(object):

    def __init__(self, model_list):
       
        # Initialize based on list parameter
        self.load(model_list)

        logger.info(f'Runner is initialized ... {model_list}')
```

When I run my system, this logging info is printed twice as below:

```
2022-03-20 11:06:04,662 - nlu.matcher.runner - INFO - 30 - Runner is initialized ... [3]
2022-03-20 11:06:04,662 - nlu.matcher.runner - INFO - 30 - Runner is initialized ... [3]
```

I use the same logger in other python files, but others don't have the same issue. I looked at this link ([Python Logger Logs Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238598/python-logger-logs-twice)). The issue is similar but not exactly the same, so I added this line to the file which has the problem, and it didn't solve the problem

```
logger.propagate = False
```

What may be the reason for twice logging in a particular file? The  following is my logger definition:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
from .configs.config import CONFIG

format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s')

abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

logger_config = CONFIG['loggers']
logger_level = CONFIG['logger_level'][0]

def my_logger(module_name):

    logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
    logger.setLevel(logger_level)

    # stream handler
    c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    c_handler.setFormatter(format)

    # debug handler
    f1_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(abspath, "logs/debug.log"))
    f1_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    f1_handler.setFormatter(format)

    # info handler
    # f2_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(abspath, "logs/info.log"))
    # f2_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # f2_handler.setFormatter(format)

    # warning handler
    f3_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(abspath, "logs/warning.log"))
    f3_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    f3_handler.setFormatter(format)

    # error handler
    f4_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(abspath, "logs/error.log"))
    f4_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    f4_handler.setFormatter(format)

    # Add handlers to the logger
    if 'stream' in logger_config:
        logger.addHandler(c_handler)
    logger.addHandler(f1_handler)
    # logger.addHandler(f2_handler)
    logger.addHandler(f3_handler)
    logger.addHandler(f4_handler)

    return logger
```

Comment: Are there any other StreamHandler added anywhere in the code?

Comment: Are you quite sure that only one `Runner` object is being instantiated? And that `my_logger` is only called once?